# Optimise pyglet script to be able to render more objects

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I built a simple script to render pixels to the screen. All the scripts does is get a random 4 characters strings of 0s and 1s (this 4 characters constitute an object), then draw the objects as pixels on the screen repeatedly.

```py
import random
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet import clock
from pyglet.window import key


W = 1280
H = 720
NUM_OBJECTS = 200
CELL_SIZE = 4
BACKGROUND_COLOR = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
OBJECT_COLOR = [241, 148, 138]


class GameWindow(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        glClearColor(*BACKGROUND_COLOR)

        self.positions = []
        self.render_objects = []
        self.main_batch = None
        self.init_objects()

    def init_objects(self):
        self.main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.render_objects = [''.join(random.choice("01") for _ in range(4)) for _ in range(4)]
        self.positions = []

        # Init positions
        current_x = 1
        current_y = 1
        for i in range(NUM_OBJECTS):
            if current_x * CELL_SIZE >= W - 4*CELL_SIZE:
                current_x = 1
                current_y += CELL_SIZE + 1

            self.positions.append((current_x, current_y))
            current_x += CELL_SIZE + 1

    def draw_object(self, position):

        row_count = position[0]
        for row in self.render_objects:
            col_count = position[1]
            for i in row:
                st_x = row_count * CELL_SIZE
                st_y = col_count * CELL_SIZE
                nd_x = st_x + CELL_SIZE
                nd_y = st_y + CELL_SIZE
                self.draw_pixel(st_x, st_y, nd_x, nd_y,
                                int(i) == 1)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.main_batch.draw()
        print(clock.get_fps())

    def reset(self):
        self.init_objects()

    def draw_pixel(self, x, y, x1, y1, is_draw, color=None):
        if not is_draw:
            return

        self.main_batch.add(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, None,
                            ('v2f', [x, y, x1, y, x1, y1, x, y1]),
                            ('c3B', (OBJECT_COLOR if color is None else color) * 4))

    def update(self, dt):
        [self.draw_object(p)
         for p in self.positions]

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.R: self.reset()

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = GameWindow(W, H)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1 / 60)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

In the above script, there are 200 objects (variable named `NUM_OBJECTS`) being rendered every frame (in batch), when I increase this number to say 500, the fps drops down to about 16.
The objects are being drawn in every `update` call because in the future I want to be able to change the positions of all these objects every frame.

My goal is to be able to render more objects on the screen (say 1k-2k objects), and I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong in the script either wrt `opengl` or wrt `pyglet`. Also is there a way I can save an opengl drawing in an object and simply add it to the batch every frame?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are constantly adding vertices every frame, which is why it degrades performance.

Your `draw_pixel` **adds** the vertices to the batch, which you are doing every frame.

What you need to do is separate your object creation from your updates. batch.add returns a vertex list you can update.

Do this only once per object and store it somewhere: `vertex_list = batch.add(..)`

Then to update the positions of the vertices you would do.
`vertex_list.vertices[:] = new_list_of_vertices`